# addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView with Fragments

Tags: java, android

i have 2 fragments in my application , i was working to make 2 pane mode for tablet UI , and its running correctly , but the one pane mode (for usual handsets) crashes every single time run the application.

this is the MainActivity..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the large-screen layouts
        // (res/layout-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the activity should be
        // in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.detail_container, new DetailFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
       else{
        mTwoPane = false;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                   .commit();
    }
```

and i have 2 activity_main.xml , on of them in the folder layout-sw600dp

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:name="com.example.moviefinal.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"/>
```

this is for the 2 pane mode(Tablet UI)..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.moviefinal.MainActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:name="com.example.moviefinal.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the in MainFragment.java

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
             db = new DBAdapter(this.getActivity());

            gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            ImageAdapter imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
            gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
```

Fragment_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:name="com.example.moviefinal.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="85dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    />
```

i got those errors :

```
10-09 14:09:15.841  16029-16029/com.example.moviefinal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.moviefinal, PID: 16029
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moviefinal/com.example.moviefinal.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
            at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:456)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:968)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

i think the GridView Layout caused this error!
any help! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:name="com.example.moviefinal.MainFragment"
```

If you declare a fragment in XML, you can't replace it programmatically with another fragment.

Just put a `FrameLayout` here and add your fragment at view creation.

Also, take this out of your `GridView` element XML:

```
android:name="com.example.moviefinal.MainFragment"
```

I think that's what's causing the "addView() not supported" heartburn.

Comment: Thank you kris, its helps, when i changed the Fragment_main.xml to FrameLayout it works correctly.

Comment: Fantastic! If it helped you fix the problem, please accept my answer as correct.